# Posting data from android app on my Twitter's account as tweet

Tags: android, twitter

I'm trying to post my data through android app on my twitter account so how should i do it.
i have tried a way, below is the code, and in that it is showing the data on my account and i need to click on the tweet button to get it tweeted. So can i know how to post it directly without asking me to tweet. Like [Four Square](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joelapenna.foursquared&hl=en) app

```
public void open(View view){
       String text = "Share Your Experiance ....!!!";
       String url = "twitter://post?message=";

       try {
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
           i.setData(Uri.parse(url + Uri.encode(text)));
           startActivity(i);
       } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Can't send tweet! Please install twitter...", 2).show();
       }
```

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: use social auth library

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to check are you logged with twitter or not after as your condition you can apply this snippet code.

I think you follow the all basics for twitter integration in your code.

```
public void uploadPic(String message, String getImgUrl)
        throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println(" ON UPLOAD PIC FUNCTION getImgUrl "+getImgUrl);
            // URL url = new URL("http://faveplatewebservice.siplstudio.com/uploads/big_dish/oooo14n7464rO4_thumb.png");
            URL url = new URL(getImgUrl);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate("Check Out FavPlates on appstore, which offers you to add and find exciting dishes near you. "+message);
            //status.setMedia(file);
            status.setMedia("Check Out FavPlates on appstore, which offers you to add and find exciting dishes near you. "+message, in);

            mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Pic Upload error" + e.getExceptionCode());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

hope it will help you!!

If  you stuck anywhere then inform me.

Thankss!!